# Asp.net MVC 4 - Route File stored in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to route my files stored in database. The URL should be : /Attachment/id/secretKey/fileName

This is my Controller :

```
public class AttachmentController : Controller {
    private IGenericRepository<Attachment> _attachmentRepository;

    public AttachmentController ( IGenericRepository<Attachment> attachmentRepository ) {
        _attachmentRepository = attachmentRepository;
    }

    public ActionResult GetAttachment ( int id, Guid secretKey, string fileName ) {
        Attachment attachment = _attachmentRepository.Get( a => a.Id == id && a.SecretKey == secretKey && a.FileName == fileName ).FirstOrDefault();

        return File( attachment.File, attachment.ContentType );
    }

}
```

This route work when my file name dont have extension

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Attachment",
            url: "Attachment/{id}/{secretKey}/{fileName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Attachment", action = "GetAttachment" }
        );
```

Example :

http://mydomain.local/Attachment/15/d230ada3-50a5-e311-adbd-001c42b3d086/Desert       WORK
http://mydomain.local/Attachment/15/d230ada3-50a5-e311-adbd-001c42b3d086/Desert.jpg   404 Because IIS is looking for a file in directory

How can I set up the route for the last link work?

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: How can I set up the route for the last link work?

Comment: Browsers don't typically like serving up files directly. I would recommend looking into returning the files via your controllers File() method.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.100).aspx